# Mongoose not returning count from mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Previously we were using the mongoose version **mongoose@3.0.1** . In that for getting the count of matches for a particular filter
criteria , we were using the following count function present in model.js :

```
Model.count = function (conditions, callback) {
  var query = new Query(conditions).bind(this, 'count');
  if ('undefined' == typeof callback)
    return query;
  var cQuery;
  if (cQuery = this._cumulativeQuery) {
    merge(query._conditions, cQuery._conditions);
    if (query.options && cQuery.options)
      merge(query.options, cQuery.options);
    delete this._cumulativeQuery;
  }
  if (!query.model) query.bind(this, 'count');
  return query.count(callback);
};
```

With the help of the above function , we will get the desired record from mongodb and if already record is present, it will return the **count as 1**.

Now we have updated the mongoose version to **mongoose@3.6.18** . In that for getting the count of matches for a particular filter
criteria , we were using the following count function present in model.js :

```
Model.count = function count (conditions, callback) {
  if ('function' === typeof conditions)
    callback = conditions, conditions = {};

  var query = new Query(conditions).bind(this, 'count');
  if ('undefined' == typeof callback)
    return query;

  this._applyNamedScope(query);
  return query.count(callback);
};

Model._applyNamedScope = function _applyNamedScope (query) {
  var cQuery = this._cumulativeQuery;

  if (cQuery) {
    merge(query._conditions, cQuery._conditions);
    if (query._fields && cQuery._fields)
      merge(query._fields, cQuery._fields);
    if (query.options && cQuery.options)
      merge(query.options, cQuery.options);
    delete this._cumulativeQuery;
  }

  return query;
}
```

With the help of the above function , we need to get the desired record from mongodb and if already record is present, it returns the **count
as null instead of 1** as in the above case and it doesnt even update the existing record . Please give your suggestions as to how to fix this.

Below I have mentioned the way in which we are connecting to mongodb and trying to fetch the record count .

```
    var mongodbconn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
    var usersschema =new Schema({
                    _id: String,
                    MemID:String,
                    Name:String
                }); 
    var users_model= mongodbconn.model('users', usersschema);
         users_model.count({MemID: '1717268'}, function (err, c) {
  if(err){
    console.log(err.stack+" Records Cnt: "+c);
  }

                 console.log("Count---------------->        " + c);
           });
```

The following response was obtained :

```
 Count---------------->        null

MongoError: [object Object]
    at toError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:110:11)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:157:34
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1670:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:382:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:472:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:430:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:191:13)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17) Records Cnt: null
```

Comment: How are you using `count`? I'm not sure why you included the source for the two functions? The implementation has changed ... but ...?

Comment: There's already a [`Model.count`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) in Mongoose. Are you sure it's not that method being called, instead of your own?

Comment: Kindly refer the above edited post , There I have mentioned how I am trying to get the count of records from mongodb .

Comment: Start checking `err`...

Comment: Kindly refer the above edited post. i have mentioned what error has came.

Comment: Try rethrowing the error instead of `console.log`ing just the stack: `if (err) throw err`. It should show the reason of the error.

Comment: getting Same error in throw err